# Other Rails templates types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Erb is the default template type in Rails and I read about Haml.

What other types exist and can be used in Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/template_languages.html).

I only know Mustache, Liquid and Markaby of those above, but seems there are pretty many other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 uses [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) by default.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to take a look at slim, which is elegant in a HAML fashion but apparently faster! https://github.com/stonean/slim